# When checking a session variable to see if a user is logged in, is it enough to check to see if the variable is set?

Tags: authentication, php

When displaying a page with content only logged in users should see, I simply check

```
if(isset($_SESSION['hasLoggedIn']))
{
  //show content
}
else
{
  echo 'you must log in';
}
```

In [this article](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) it recommends checking the IP address and browser each time.

```
$_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password.$ip_address.$user_browser);
```

Is this necessary? I thought since session variables only existed on the server they are not prone to attack? I kind of don't get why `$password` is there. If the password is being passed to each page, wouldn't it be easier for the database with the userid/password to be queried, or is the idea that this way the database doesn't need to be queried (which is time consuming)?

Comment: You should check out [this list of secure session practices](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/1250/396)

Comment: @makerofthings7 must I know about session hijacking to understand what is going on here?

Comment: Yes, it is enough to check whether the session is set or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other things to consider to get a secure session handling, like using SSL, regeneratig the session id, and more. But to get the login state from the session, it is enough to test if a certain value is set, like you did.

Of course you can store additional information about the user connetion in the session, but password and ip-address are not appropriate. Especially the password should not be stored plaintext on server-side, and that is what you need to check the hash in your example. The ip-address is not a reliable information, it could be dynamic and change during the visit of the user. In this case the user would be denied access, even if he had logged in successfully before.

If you want to store additional information, i would recommend to write this fingerprint into a separate variable like $_SESSION['client_fingerprint']. There is an article from [Chris Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/articles/the-truth-about-sessions) (see section: *Preventing Impersonation*), it shows that there are not many informations appropriate to generate this fingerprint.

Comment: How frequently would the IP address change? If the IP changes every day I think it's still a good idea to check it.

Comment: I answered my own question. "Most notably, a single user can potentially use a different IP address for each request (as is the case with large ISPs such as AOL)"